# jQuery CSS manipulation not working

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to color the text in `#fav` red using jQuery, but it is not working.

HTML

```
<div id="favorite">
  <p id="fav"> "favorite"</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#fav').click(function(){
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

It all seems to be correct, I've checked my links are all correct by testing a simple `.onload` alert but I've been stuck with this for a while now.

Comment: I edited your codes, just check.

Comment: Your code seems correct; without a MCV example we cannot really help much. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Is the jQuery code after the element, or in `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure(DEBUG) that no other css rule have higher priority.
try this:

```
$('#fav').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red !important');
});
```

and share the result.

Comment: no luck, also there is no CSS file currently :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should work, check out https://jsfiddle.net/1jLrxaco/
Just make sure you include jQuery into the project and put your JavaScript code between `<script>`-tags (or put it into a JS-source).

Edit: remove the spaces in the jQuery source: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-    3.1.0.min.js`

Comment: I tried a separate source file rather than linking to the page as shown in my code but still this hasn't changed the issue. I tried it with Mattan Bitners code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler should only be registered when Dom is ready

```
$(document).ready(

$('#fav').click(function(){ 
$(this).css('color', 'red'); });

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried creating a small similar sample for you, which is working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="test">If you click on me, I will turn red.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this.